# NodeJS piping child stdout to response; first highWaterMark bytes of output stream lost

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I was writing some nodejs code to open a file read stream, pipe it to a child made with spawn(), and then pipe the child's stdout to the response.
I solved my problem; I am posting this to help others and also because I don't understand why one way worked and the other didn't.

My first try was:

```
const  fs  = require('fs');
const  spawn  = require('child_process').spawn;
var fstream= fs.createReadStream('/tmp/whatever_binary_file.exe, {highWaterMark: 1024});
fstream.on('open', function () {
    const child = spawn(
        './scripts/do_stuff.pl',
        [arg1,arg2,arg3 ],
        {
            stdio: [fstream,'pipe' ,process.stderr]
        }
    );
    child.stdout.pipe(res);
});
```

This didn't work, the output file in the response was always missing exactly its first highWaterMark bytes. If I remove the highWaterMark option, then it was missing its first 64KB bytes (the default I guess).

My second try worked:

```
const  fs  = require('fs');
const  spawn  = require('child_process').spawn;
var fstream= fs.createReadStream('/tmp/whatever_binary_file.exe, {highWaterMark: 1024});
fstream.on('open', function () {
    const child = spawn(
        './scripts/do_stuff.pl',
        [arg1,arg2,arg3 ],
        {
            stdio: ['pipe','pipe' ,process.stderr]
        }
    );
    fstream.pipe(child.stdin);
    child.stdout.pipe(res);
});
```

But why? What's the difference exactly between these two attempts?
The stdio option documentation says I can pass a Stream object or 'pipe'. It also says that stdio is 'used to configure the pipes that are established between the parent and child process.' So, I read this and expected no difference between the two tries. What am I missing?